# Why does the same method fail when inside an Array extension in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm getting strange behavior when trying to call `sort()` from within an Array extension, e.g this method:

```
func test() {
    let a = [1,2,3]
    sort(a) { x, y in x < y }
}
```

Works on its own, but fails when its inside an `Array` extension:

```
extension Array {
    func test() {
        let a = [1,2,3]
        sort(a) { x, y in x < y }
    }
}
```

It's a build error, failing with:

> Extra argument in call

Curiously the same method works as a `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func test() {
        let a = [1,2,3]
        sort(a) { x, y in x < y }
    }
}
```

Why can't I call `sort()` from within an Array extension?

Comment: My guess would be that `Array` already has a method `sort` (which does not take two parameters) and you get that one instead of the global `sort` function.

Comment: Re: "My guess would be". Is there an online API doc for the built-in types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Array` has a method called `sort` of its own, which is of the form `sort(isOrderedBefore: (T, T) -> Bool)`

So, when you call `sort` inside the scope of `Array`, you are actually referring to that version instead of the global `sort` function.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092862/1371070) in a question of mine, I found that you can make sure you're calling the `sort` version in the global scope by using  Swift's default namespace, Swift. So, the global version is accessible via `Swift.sort`.

Comment: Yep that looks like it! Do you know how we can call the global `sort`?

Comment: Nope, but I am trying to find out. Definitely looks like there should be a way to do it.

Comment: You could call `a.sort() { x, y in x < y }` I suppose.

Comment: @Cezar k thx, can't find anything myself. If you end up finding anything feel free extend your answer!

Comment: @mythz, I asked a separate question on the subject. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24050430/1371070. Feel free to edit if you can think of a better wording to explain the issue.

Comment: @mythz Hey, my question was answered and it works. I edited my answer here linking to it and explaining the solution. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Awesome! appreciated :)