# Calling a global function which has the same name as a member function

Tags: swift

The `Array` type in Swift has a member function called `sort`, with its signature being `sort(isOrderedBefore: (T, T) -> Bool)`. This function differs from the global version of `sort`, which has the signature `sort(array: T[], pred: (T, T) -> Bool)`.

If one extends an `Array` (see [Why does the same method fail when inside an Array extension in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24050102/1371070)), calling `sort` from inside the scope of the `Array` extension will naturally result in the local version being used.

Is it possible to explicitly call a function from an outer scope, or specifically from the global scope, even if its name coincides with that of a function from an inner scope?

This would be similar to the C++ scoping resolution operator, `::`

Comment: Ah, you mean like C++'s global scoping operator `::`? Interesting question.

Comment: @Yawar, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Chris Lattner suggests](https://twitter.com/clattner_llvm/status/474772713739792384) qualifying the name of the global function with Swift's default namespace, `Swift`. So you should be able to access the global version using: `Swift.sort`.

Comment: ah, but what if it's not in Swift, but in the local module?

Comment: @AlexBrown if your target name is "MyApp" you can call the global function with MyApp.theGlobalFunction(). I had a similar conflict with the global functions of Alamofire (to target iOS7 you can't use embedded frameworks and so the lib isn't namespaced)

Comment: @MathieuLescure I didn't find that `MyApp.theGlobal` works. Has that feature gone away since you wrote this?

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the global `sort`, for example,

```
func my_sort<T>(arr: T[], pred: (T, T) -> Bool) -> T[] {
    return sort(arr, pred)
}
```