# Calling a global function which has the same name as a member function Part 2

Tags: swift

Directly related to [Calling a global function which has the same name as a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050430/calling-a-global-function-which-has-the-same-name-as-a-member-function), I'm wondering how to call a global function in my own module.

I have a project named Parsing that is a Cocoa Framework. The name of my Xcode target is Parsing.

I have a function named failure at the framework level, and I'm attempting to call it from within a member of a type that has the same name.

I can obviously work around this by changing names; but I'm more curious about why the qualified name isn't working for me.

I get the compile error `Use of unresolved identifier 'Parsing'` in the following code:

```
import Foundation
//import Parsing;

func failure<T>() -> ParserOf<T> {
    return ParserOf { inp in nil }
}

class ParserOf<T> {
    let _parser:String -> (T, String)?;
    private init(_ p:String -> (T, String)?) {
        _parser = p;
    }

    func parse(s:String) -> (T, String)? {
        return _parser(s);
    }

    class func failure() -> ParserOf<T> {
        return Parsing.failure(); // compile error
    }

}
```

If I uncomment the `import Parsing` line then I get a compiler error that says `Cannot load underlying module for 'parsing'` which looks a little odd because the casing of the name in the error message doesn't match the casing of the actual name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do that by importing the framework like you did in your commented code:

```
import Parsing
```

and then using the full name, including the namespace (module), again like you did:

```
Parsing.failure()
```

You should check that:

- the entity you are trying to access to (in this case a function) is declared as `public`
- the module name (`Parsing`) is correct
- the function is actually a global function and not a class/struct method
- target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Module Name is the actual model name you are trying to import

Last, if you change the name of the `class func failure()` method, does it work?

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the original project and started from scratch and it does now work as you indicate. I uncommented my import line and everything works.