# Issues about Array Extension for sort

Tags: swift

I am trying out a small extension to Array type that sorts elements in descending order. I have read other resolutions on the topic including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050102/why-does-the-same-method-fail-when-inside-an-array-extension-in-swift). But I get an error:

> error: could not find an overload for 'sort' that accepts the >supplied arguments return Swift.sort(self) {$0 > $1}

Could anyone help on how to resolve this: The code below

```
extension Array {
  func sortAsc()->T[] {
     return Swift.sort(self) {$0 > $1}
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Afaik Generic Extensions are not possible. if so they'd do that in their own libary
so what about using a normal func?

```
func sortAsc<T:Comparable>(data: T[])->T[] {
    return Swift.sort(data) {$1 > $0}
}
```

Comment: Ok. Got it. However, I did see an implementation of sum() as an extension or an Array in the forum. Can we have a type specific implementation of sortAsc say for Int

Comment: what do you mean "Generic Extensions are not possible"? any reference?

Comment: Array is `Array<T>` but to be able to sort it has to be `Array<T: Comparable>`but Swift does not allow `extension Array<T: Comparable>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func sortDesc()->Array {
        return sort(>)
    }
}

[5, 3, 9].sortDesc() // returns [9, 5, 3]
```